# Integrating Spring with JavaFX Service class causes Service to fail

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, javafx

**Background**

I am working on a JavaFX application to manage, edit, and move files for me automatically based on my preferences. Ultimately, the application will have quite a few tasks that will require some heavy processing. I would like to have a single task bar displayed at the bottom of the screen that can be utilized and displayed by each task when it is running and hidden otherwise.

Due to the fact that the tasks can be quite time consuming I would like to also have a cancel task icon displayed next to the progress bar that can also be universal and cancel which ever task is currently being executed when clicked.

**My Thought Process**

To accomplish this the solution I have come up with to the best of my ability is to create a unique class extending Task for each task my application would have, this class would be a normal (non-spring bean) class.

Then also create a unique class extending Service for each one one of these tasks, then within the service class the overridden createTask() method would return a new instance of the respective Task. However, this service class would be a spring bean and could therefore be Autowired into any controller class that needed to use the service to run the task.

**The Problem**

When ever I click the button that ultimately starts the service, the service ends up failing and being put into a state of FAILED. When I look at the debugger it seems as if the exception is occurring because of a null pointer exception due to the file browser controller being null. However, the file browser controller should be getting Autowired into the task class when it is instantiated by the service createTask() method.

I am not 100% certain that this is the cause of the problem since debugging the service has proven to be a little challenging, but it seems as if it is because this is the exception that is set to the Task value right before service is set to 'Failed'

**Code**

*Controller class (starts service)*

```
@Component
public class FileBrowserController implements Initializable {

    @Autowired
    private GetSelectedFilesCountService getSelectedFilesCountService;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        // Code to build the file browser tree
    }


     /*******************************************************************************************************
     ***************************               BUTTON FUNCTIONALITY               ***************************                                       
     *        Gets the total count of leaf files from the users selection in the File Browser window        *
     ********************************************************************************************************/

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {

        // Initially set value to 0 and then bind the value with the service value property, 
        // which ultimately gets its value form the GetSelectedFilesCountTask 
        ObjectProperty<Integer> fileCount = new SimpleObjectProperty<Integer>(0);
        fileCount.bind(getSelectedFilesCountService.valueProperty());


        // On success print the value to the screen to check that this is working properly
        getSelectedFilesCountService.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(WorkerStateEvent event) {
                System.out.println("The Service was successful, file count: " + fileCount.get());
            }
        });

        if(getSelectedFilesCountService.getState() == Service.State.READY) {
            getSelectedFilesCountService.start();
        }
        else if(getSelectedFilesCountService.getState() != Service.State.RUNNING 
                || getSelectedFilesCountService.getState() != Service.State.SCHEDULED) {
            getSelectedFilesCountService.reset();
            getSelectedFilesCountService.start();
        }
    }
}
```

*Service Class (creates and returns new Task instance)*

```
@Component
public class GetSelectedFilesCountService extends Service<Integer> {

    @Override
    protected Task<Integer> createTask() {
        return new GetSelectedFilesCountTask();
    }   
}
```

*Task Class, performs the actual task*

```
@Component
public class GetSelectedFilesCountTask extends Task<Integer> {

    @Autowired
    private FileBrowserController fileBrowserController;

    private Integer leafCount;

    @Override
    protected Integer call() {
        leafCount = 0;
        getSelectedItemsCount(fileBrowserController.getFileBrowser().getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());
        return leafCount;
    }

    /*****************************************************************
     *Recursively counts the leaves within a single or group of Files 
     *****************************************************************/
    private void getSelectedItemsCount(List<TreeItem<File>> files) {

        for(TreeItem<File> f : files) {
            if(f.isLeaf()) {
                leafCount++;
            }else {
                getSelectedItemsLeafCount(f.getChildren());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void cancelled() {
        updateMessage("Operation Cancelled");
    }
}
```

*Spring Config File*

```
@Configuration
public class SpringAppConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataModel datamodel() {
        return new DataModel();
    }

    @Bean
    public GetSelectedFilesCountService getSelectedFilesCountService() {
        return new GetSelectedFilesCountService();
    }
}
```

**Solutions I have Tried**

Originally I wanted to also declare the Tasks as prototype spring beans and then Autowire them into the service as properties and then return the autowired value in the createTask() method. This solution would work the first time I clicked the button but then the second time it would throw an exception because Spring would only create a new instance of the task property on the first pass and then once the service was reset and the task was set to null it would never get created again. see below for snippet

*Service with Autowired Task*

```
@Component
public class GetSelectedFilesCountService extends Service<Integer> {

    @Autowired
    private GetSelectedFilesCountTask getSelectedFilesCountTask;

    @Override
    protected Task<Integer> createTask() {
        return getSelectedFilesCountTask;
    }   
}
```

After this, I decided that maybe I could still accomplish the above by creating a bean factory for the tasks and then calling the bean factory's createBean() method to return a new instance of the task, but ultimately this didn't work and I felt as if I could accomplish the same thing by basically using the service as factory for creating the new instances with only half the code.

**UPDATE**

I still would like to know what was the original issue with the code above (returning a new instance of the Task sub-class), but for now I have found a solution .... or workaround by creating and returning an anonymous Task instance. I guess this is acceptable because I won't have to repeat the code because the service can be used multiple times but I'd still prefer to have the code within its own class. It's strange because this is literally the same exact code that I had in the Task subclass that kept failing but I guess. Please see below for the snippet in case it will be helpful to someone else.

```
@Component
public class GetSelectedFilesCountService extends Service<Integer> {

    @Autowired
    private FileBrowserController fileBrowserController;

    private Integer leafCount;

    @Override
    protected Task<Integer> createTask() {

        return new Task<Integer>() {

            @Override
            protected Integer call() {
                leafCount = 0;
                getSelectedItemsLeafCount(fileBrowserController.getFileBrowser().getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());
                return leafCount;
            }

            /*****************************************************************
             *Recursively counts the leaves within a single or group of Files 
             *****************************************************************/
            private void getSelectedItemsLeafCount(List<TreeItem<File>> files) {

                for(TreeItem<File> f : files) {
                    if(f.isLeaf()) {
                        leafCount++;
                    }else {
                        getSelectedItemsLeafCount(f.getChildren());
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a complete solution, but a decent work-around is to use and return an anonymous task from within the createTask method in the service. For some reason there is an issue when I try to return a new instance of a defined subclass of Task where the spring bean doesn't get instantiated, please comment if you know why this is.

*Solution*

```
@Component
public class GetSelectedFilesCountService extends Service<Integer> {

    @Autowired
    private FileBrowserController fileBrowserController;

    private Integer leafCount;

    @Override
    protected Task<Integer> createTask() {

        return new Task<Integer>() {

            @Override
            protected Integer call() {
                leafCount = 0;
                getSelectedItemsLeafCount(fileBrowserController.getFileBrowser().getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());
                return leafCount;
            }

            /*****************************************************************
             *Recursively counts the leaves within a single or group of Files 
             *****************************************************************/
            private void getSelectedItemsLeafCount(List<TreeItem<File>> files) {

                for(TreeItem<File> f : files) {
                    if(f.isLeaf()) {
                        leafCount++;
                    }else {
                        getSelectedItemsLeafCount(f.getChildren());
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }   
}
```